# Modal closes when changing state of input inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this modal. When I press the button "CHANGE" I want to enable the input contactModalPhoneInput. What happens is when I click the button it immediately closes the modal. When I reopen it, it has efectively enable the input.  Any ideas?

```
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Results</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactModalPhoneInput" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled/>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnChangePhone" onclick="changeInputState()">Change</button>
```

Update
                    Close

```
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove 'data-dismiss="modal"' from your btnChangePhone